# How to work with Matrices for 3D Models and Camera

Tags: c#, matrix, monogame

This is my first time here. I'm confused on how to use Matrices for a 3D model's World View Projection variables. I wanted to know if someone would give me a detailed example of camera rotation around the Azimuth angle, and up/down the Elevation angle? Such as changing the camera's position, but having it still face the target location.

General tips are also acceptable if no one has a definite answer to my question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider reformatting your question to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".